# Fail2Ban regex where IP is on one line and failure message on another

Tags: regex, multiline

I'm trying to create a regular expression to match Xen's XAPI log. The problem is that the IP is stored on the first line and the failure message on the second. Here's an example:

```
Jan  8 23:07:42 myserver stunnel: LOG5[6732:3073162128]: xapi connected from 1.1.1.1:55002
Jan  8 23:07:42 myserver xapi: pam_unix(xapi:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=root
```

The regular expression I have is:

```
^.*xapi connected from <HOST>:[0-9]*\n.*xapi: pam_unix.xapi:auth.: authentication failure;.*$
```

This works fine in VI (obviously without ) but not in fail2ban. My testing seems to indicate that the problem is the \n. Is this possible with fail2ban?

I found this Stackoverflow article: [Can regex match be based on two lines of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962204/can-regex-match-be-based-on-two-lines-of-text). I am simply treating the line feed as a character. Has anyone developed a Fail2Ban filter that supports information on multiple lines? (I'm using Fail2Ban v0.8.4. if it matters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using fail2ban v0.9.0, this is possible (didn't check older versions). You do have to specify the `maxlines` option. Try following filter file:

```
[Init]
maxlines = 2

[Definition]

failregex = ^.*xapi connected from <HOST>:[0-9]*\n.*xapi: pam_unix.xapi:auth.: authentication failure;.*$

ignoreregex =
```

Comment: I wish I could mark this correct for you - this was exactly the piece of information I needed

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't know Fail2Ban. One possible issue is that you use both `^` and `&` along with `\n`. I don't think they mix well. They are different and concurrent ways to indicate line bounds.

You better use `\n` systematically.

Also replace .* with .*?, to avoid spawning over the whole log...

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I think it's an issue with how Fail2Ban is using the regexp. Thanks anyway.