# How to combine multiple grep commands?

Tags: linux, grep

I have a long .txt file (`LONG.txt`). In that txt file, I want to search for 3 types of patterns and then I want to capture the grep result into a new txt file (`SHORT.txt`).

Patterns:

1. `AAAAA`
2. `BBBBB`
3. `CCCCC`

**NOTE**:

When pattern `AAAAA` or `BBBBB` is found, I want to print only that line which contain `AAAAA` or `BBBBB`.

When pattern `CCCCC` is found, I want to print that line which contain `CCCCC` + next 1 line.

Example:

`LONG.txt`:

```
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
something something AAAAA something something
bla bla 
bla bla 
something something CCCCC something something
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
something something BBBBB something something
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
something something AAAAA something something
bla bla 
something something AAAAA something something
bla bla 
something something BBBBB something something
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
something something CCCCC something something
bla bla
bla bla
bla bla
```

Output should be:

```
something something AAAAA something something
something something CCCCC something something
bla bla 
something something BBBBB something something
something something AAAAA something something
something something AAAAA something something
something something BBBBB something something
something something CCCCC something something
bla bla
```

What I tried is:

```
grep -B0 "AAAAA" LONG.txt > SHORT.txt
grep -B0 "BBBBB" LONG.txt > SHORT.txt
grep -B1 "CCCCC" LONG.txt > SHORT.txt
```

But this doesn't give me desired output.

Comment: Is the order of the lines in the output important?

Comment: Yes, text sequence should not be lost.

Comment: Your first 2 commands for AAA and BBB can be clubbed together, but then it will not be `Search A, Then Search B`. It will be like `Search A or Search B`, which would be efficient, both these ways also differ in term of their order.. I guess that's what @Biffen is also trying to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk '/AAA|BBB|CCC/ {print; if ($0 ~ /CCC/) {getline; print;} }'`

Answer (score 5):

Your code would keep overwriting the file because you used a single arrow.

Use a single arrow the first time and double arrows subsequent times to append to the file.

```
grep "AAAAA" LONG.txt > SHORT.txt
grep "BBBBB" LONG.txt >> SHORT.txt
grep -A1 "CCCCC" LONG.txt >> SHORT.txt
```

The first two `grep` commands print just the line with the match and the last one prints the line and one line after.

---

Additional explanation of `grep`:

By default it returns just the matching lines. If you pass the `-A` flag with a number it will show the matching lines and that number of lines after. E.g. `-A1` prints the matching line and the next line as per your request. Similarly, the `-B` flag prints lines before the match.

Remember: `-A` = After, `-B` = Before.

---

*UPDATE*

There's the additional requirement that the output retain the order in which they appeared in the original file.

Here's a script to do it:

```
grep -n "AAAAA" LONG.txt > SHORT.txt
grep -n "BBBBB" LONG.txt >> SHORT.txt
grep -n -A1 "CCCCC" LONG.txt >> SHORT.txt
sort -n -o SHORT.txt SHORT.txt

sed -i 's/^[0-9]\+//' SHORT.txt
sed -i 's/^.//g' SHORT.txt
```

Only main difference here is that I use the `-n` flag in the `grep` to print the line numbers then I use `sort` to sort the file by these line numbers. The line numbers will still be present in this output file, so you may want to remove those.

Comment: I will loose my sequence if I will do that

Comment: Throw `grep` a `-n` flag and it will print out the line numbers then you can reorder them.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to do it manually. I will be firing a script file which will be doing all tasks for me [i.e., converting long.txt into short.txt]

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my answer to include this requirement.

Comment: Yes, that works. Only thing is extra line numbers are visible. Please tell me how to remove those line numbers as well. Thank you so much. Thats exactly what I was expecting

Comment: sed -i 's/^[0-9]\+ //' SHORT.txt

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/AAAAA\|BBBBB/p;/CCCCC/{N;p}' LONG.txt > SHORT.txt
```

Explanation

- `/AAAAA\|BBB/` searches for AAAAA or BBBBB `p` prints the current line (=Pattern buffer)
- `/CCCCC/` searches for CCCCC and 
  `N` reads the next line into the buffer
  `p` prints the current buffer