# how to extend my Perl regular expression to remove matching pattern even if there is a line break in between

Tags: regex, perl

I am facing problem in writing a generic regular expression which will help me clean up the unwanted HTML attributes from my input text.
My input looks like this

```
<p data-bind="XYZ" style="text-align: center;">Untitled Template1 - art</p>
<p><select data-bind="
            options:options,
            optionsText: 'value',
            optionsValue: 'id',
            value: value,
            optionsCaption:'Please select',
            attr: { id: 'select'+id }"><option style="text-align: center;" value="8661"></option><option value="8662"></option></select></p>
```

I have pushed both of these strings into an array. I am looping the array and clearing the `data-bind` attribute.

```
foreach my $row ( @$results ) {
    $value =~ s/\sdata-bind=".*?"//g;
}
```

Result looks like this:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">Untitled Template1 - art</p>
<p><select data-bind="
            options:options,
            optionsText: 'value',
            optionsValue: 'id',
            value: value,
            optionsCaption:'Please select',
            attr: { id: 'select'+id }"><option style="text-align: center;" value="8661"></option><option value="8662"></option></select></p>
```

How to eliminate `data-bind` attribute from my second string. Can any one help.
I searched Stackoverflow and found a user asking the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962204/can-regex-match-be-based-on-two-lines-of-text). The answer mentioned in the above line states that regular expression can span more than one line but that isn't happening in my case.

Comment: `$value =~ s/\sdata-bind=".*?"//gs;`

Comment: `.` refer to any character except newline. @ssr1012 answered with regex that works for your case. with `s` flag `.` matches newline.

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex. Use a parser, you'll find many on CPAN.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $str = "<p data-bind=\"XYZ\" style=\"text-align: center;\">Untitled Template1 - art</p>
<p><select data-bind=\"
        options:options,
        optionsText: 'value',
        optionsValue: 'id',
        value: value,
        optionsCaption:'Please select',
        attr: { id: 'select'+id }\"><option style=\"text-align: center;\" value=\"8661\"></option><option value=\"8662\"></option></select></p>";
```

> If you are using in the multi-line replacement it should be use `s` modifier.

```
    $str=~s/\sdata-bind=".*?"//gs;

    print $str;
```